# Object-c url data encryption

Tags: asp.net, ios, objective-c, web-services

I have an iPhone app that will call web-service on asp.net server. e.g. http://server.ws.com/projects.wsdl?i=10. The web service is written in c#.

I want to encrypt the url on the iPhone app and decrypt it again on the asp.net website correctly so I don't lose any data.

Thanks.

Comment: use https, and let the transport encryption do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Explain a little more in order to get a specific answer, "encrypt the url" is a vague.

Answer (score 1):

C# has some really good native encryption classes. The trick is ensuring the implementation is the same for the C encryption, and the C# encryption.

After a quick google search this is what I've come up with:

The apple tutorial gives some information about encryption is Objective C on the iPhone: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172

Here are some things that you need to consider:

How you're going to make the connection, 
How you're going to establish a key on both sides : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange 
Encrypting the information using a predefined algorithm. 
Transmitting the encrypted data along the connection. This last one shouldn't be too difficult.

Hopefully this will be helpful :)

Comment: No problem. Also keep in mind the strength of your encryption, if it doesn't say it in the link! If this has answered your question, be sure to mark it as the answer for future readers :)